# Is refund() a reserved keyword in Solidity now?

Tags: solidity

using:

```
solc@0.5.16
truffle@5.1.7
```

and in my smart contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
```

When I have a function name **refund()** I received the following warning message (just a comma). The warning goes away as soon as I rename the function.

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\MyCoin.sol
> Compilation warnings encountered:
,
```

Edit. I managed to reproduce with minimal line of code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
contract MyTest {
    function refund() internal {  }
    function test(uint refund) public {
        uint i = refund;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, refund isn't a reserved word in solidity.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;

contract MyTest {
    function refund() internal {  }
    function test(uint refund) public {
        uint i = refund;
    }
}
```

The warning shown by solc

```
Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
    function test(uint refund) public {
                  ^---------^
browser/3_Ballot.sol:6:5: The shadowed declaration is here:
    function refund() internal {  }
    ^-----------------------------^
```

Is caused by having a variable or parameter with the same name as a function.

If you rename both to `foobar` it will cause the same warning.

Comment: But the function name and the parameters are in different scope. The worst is solc do not throw a proper warning message. It took me quite some time to figure out what had went wrong by commenting out line by line in a 600+ lines of source code.

Comment: @sk The problem is `refund` function cannot be called from `test`. It might not be a problem in your case, but solc is trying to warn about that.

Comment: Hhmm... I wonder why you can see the warning message, but I can't. Anyway it seems like solc confused between a param name with function name. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well, it's not a good idea to have a function parameter called the same thing as as an actual function on the contract.  When I stick this code in remix it generates this warning:

```
browser/sdfsdf.sol:4:19: Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
    function test(uint refund) public {
                  ^---------^
browser/sdfsdf.sol:3:5: The shadowed declaration is here:
    function refund() internal {  }
    ^-----------------------------^
}
```

which seems legit to me.  I'd suggest changing one or the other